# Most efficient way using jQuery to verify that all fields of two modules have been completed?

Tags: jquery, performance

The following code checks to ensure that a user has completed three values of at least two modules (that are dynamically added using jQuery).

How can this be updated to make it more efficient?

```
if ( $('.product-name').eq(0).val() == '' && $('.product-url').eq(0).val() == '' && $('.product-category').eq(0).val() == '' ) {
  console.log('Please complete at least two modules.');
}

if ( $('.product-name').eq(1).val() == '' && $('.product-url').eq(1).val() == '' && $('.product-category').eq(1).val() == '' ) {
  console.log('Please complete at least two modules.');
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your HTML as well. Are you guaranteed to have the same number of `product-name`, `product-url` and `product-category` classes?

Comment: Yes -- each module will contain all three fields/classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably store your jQuery results as arrays, then write this as a loop so you aren't running the selectors multiple times.

**Note:** when using [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toarray/) you get DOM elements, not jQuery objects, so the JavaScript is slightly modified.

```
var completeCount = 0;
var productNames = $('.product-name').toArray();
var productUrls = $('.product-url').toArray();
var productCategories = $('.product-category').toArray();

for(var i = 0; i < productNames.length; i++) {
  if (productNames[i].value !== '' && productUrls[i].value !== '' && productCategories [i].value !== '') {
    completeCount++;
  }
  if (completeCount === 2) {
    break;
  }
}

if (completeCount < 2) {
  console.log('Please complete at least two modules.');
}
```

Comment: Hi dave, Thanks for helping. I'm getting an error if no modules were added, hence the classes don't exist within the section. How can a check be added to make sure at least two modules were added, then that all three fields were completed for at least two?

Comment: I updated the answer. I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks again dave! The three val()'s were throwing an "undefined is not a function" error. I changed them to value and that did the trick. Any ideas why? Shouldn't val() and value produce the same result??

Comment: Sorry about that... when calling .`toArray()` you get the DOM elements back, not the jQuery objects, so you need to use `.value`. I updated the answer for clarity.